# Swift bitmask, how to know if a int is contained in a bitmask?

Tags: swift, bitmask

I need to understand how to know if a bitmask value has an OptionSet value that comes from my API. My OptionSet is this:

```
struct RecordsObjectivesStates: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) {self.rawValue = rawValue}
    static let None                             = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let RecordRedeemed                   = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let RewardUnavailable                = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let ObjectiveNotCompleted            = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let Obscured                         = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 8)
    static let Invisible                        = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 16)
    static let EntitlementUnowned               = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 32)
    static let CanEquipTitle                    = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 64)
}
```

I have a response value of "20" from API. That is ObjectiveNotCompleted+Invisible. I want to know if Invisible is in my "20" value (and is it, obviously).

I found a lot of explanations about hexadecimal values or binary values, but nothing about Int values. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should be declaring the constants as powers of two, not 1 shifted left by powers of 2. It is convention to use 1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2, 1 << 3, 1 << 4 etc. when defining the individual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that the value 20 clearly contains the value `invisible`. But this is incorrect. You have defined `invisible` as `1 << 16`. That is 65536. The value 20 certainly does not contain 65536.

So you first need to fix your OptionSet. You should also name the constants starting with lowercase letters.

```swift
struct RecordsObjectivesStates: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: Int

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    static let recordRedeemed        = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 0) // 1
    static let rewardUnavailable     = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 1) // 2
    static let objectiveNotCompleted = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 2) // 4
    static let obscured              = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 3) // 8
    static let invisible             = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 4) // 16
    static let entitlementUnowned    = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 5) // 32
    static let canEquipTitle         = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 6) // 64
}
```

Now with those changes (note the removal of `None`), the constants have the correct values. And now the value 20 does in fact contain `invisible` (16).

```swift
let states = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 20)

if states.contains(.invisible) {
    // do stuff
}
```

You do not need the `none` value because that's easily represented by the empty option set which is what you get with a raw value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

As Geoff notes, `<< n` means "shift left by `n`" which provides an easy way to define powers of two. You rarely would shift by powers of two. So the correct definition would be:

```
struct RecordsObjectivesStates: OptionSet {
    var rawValue: Int
    static let recordRedeemed        = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let rewardUnavailable     = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let objectiveNotCompleted = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let obscured              = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let invisible             = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let entitlementUnowned    = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 5)
    static let canEquipTitle         = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 1 << 6)

    // Generally shouldn't do this, but for demonstration
    static let none: RecordsObjectivesStates = []
}
```

I've provided `.none` because you did, but usually you wouldn't. You'd just use `[]` to express it. It's generally clearer that way.

With this, you can create a value with 20:

```
let value = RecordsObjectivesStates(rawValue: 20)
```

And check whether it contains particular values with `.contains`:

```
value.contains(.invisible)
```

A reason that you shouldn't generally define `.none` is that it allows code like `value.contain(.none)`, which is always true because every set includes the empty set. This is confusing, but sometime people still find it useful to have the constant.